# html format assign to java string

Tags: java

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <form role="form">
            <div class="tablecontainer">
            </div>
            </form>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Hi is there any tool or shortcut which can be used for storing the above to a Java String. Manually doing is totally tiredness.
This is a small code. There are chances to have more lines to be there. I thought doing through message.properties. But
the format is not coming properly. so again i have to format and make it into single line.Again tiredness. And I cannot use java file reading due to some problem.

Comment: Wait, why are you embedding html in java?

Comment: Java does not have a multi lined string syntax like some languages (python for example has """). Your best bet is to store it in a file and read that into a string at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googling `html to java constant online` comes up with this online tool pretty quickly: http://www.htmlescape.net/javaescape_tool.html, which in turn generates this for you:

```
String s="<div class=\"container\">\n <div class=\"row\">\n <form role=\"form\">\n <div class=\"tablecontainer\">\n </div>\n </form>\n </div>\n </div>";
```